# How to set a loop for drawing poly lines

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I have an app that sets co-ordinates for Markit. I am trying to structure a loop so that it will repeat for the number of co-ordinates that I have. however I can't seem to get it to work. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I am trying to draw these poly lines between the start and end co-ordinates. I will be adding in a lot of co-ordinates in the future s I need to get the loop sorted.

```
  struct Location {
    let title: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
      }

      let locationsStart = [
    Location(title: "Start",    latitude: 52.100525, longitude: -9.623071)
]

let locationsEnd = [
    Location(title: "End",    latitude: 52.07241, longitude: -9.575299)
]

for location in locationsStart {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location.title
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let directionRequestZone1 = MKDirections.Request()
    let zonePlacemarkS = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: zonePlacemarkS)
    directionRequestZone1.transportType = .automobile
}

for location in locationsEnd {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location.title
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let directionRequestZone1 = MKDirections.Request()
    let zonePlacemarkE = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: zonePlacemarkE)
    directionRequestZone1.transportType = .automobile

    let directions1 = MKDirections(request: directionRequestZone1)
    directions1.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let directionResonse = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("we have error getting directions==\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }

        let route = directionResonse.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)


        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
    }
}
       //set delegate for mapview
       self.mapView.delegate = self
  }


  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
renderer.lineWidth = 5.0
return renderer
  }
```

Comment: Do not repeat your own question please. You've set a bounty on your earlier question; now wait for it to attract some answers.

Comment: Unrelated: don't destructure `latitude` and `longitude` into two separate `Double`s. You end up just passing the two double around, and calling `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)` anyway. Everytime you have to type or copy/past "latitude" or "longitude" is a new opportunity for a typo.